# Taylor expansion for a function with two vectors as variable

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm currently dealing with a function $f$ that takes two vectors as variables, namely $x$ and $u$. What I want to do is to express the quantity $f(x+\delta x, u+\delta u)$ - $f(x,u)$. I have an expression for when $x$ and $u$ are vectors of size one, but for greater dimensions I have no clue about the solution.

Thank you all for reading this!

Answer (score 0):

The $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ case is quite similar to the $\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ case:
$$f(x + \delta x)=f(x)+\delta x_i \frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x_i}+\frac{1}{2}\delta x_i \delta x_j \frac{\partial^2 f(x)}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}+\frac{1}{3!}\delta x_i \delta x_j \delta x_k \frac{\partial^3 f(x)}{\partial x_i\partial x_j \partial x_k} + \dots$$
Where $x, \delta x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and I was using Einstein's notation.
And note that if $f$ is a $\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}$ function, then you can treat it as a $\mathbb{R^{n+m}} \to \mathbb{R}$ function.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer

Comment: @RabbitMessi You're welcome. Did I answer your question(s)?

Comment: Yep it's now clear in my mind. I have another question though. In a paper, I read about $\frac{\partial f(x,u)}{\partial x}$. Is it the line vector: $\frac{\partial f(x,u)}{\partial x_{1}}, \frac{\partial f(x,u)}{\partial x_{2}}, ..., \frac{\partial f(x,u)}{\partial x_{n}}$?

Comment: @RabbitMessi Could you link the paper or a picture of it?